# Is it possible to get linked.cs files to use available namespaces in current solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If I link a .cs file from external folder using the ["add as link"](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2019/07/linking-files-in-visual-studio.html) option, is it possible to configure it such that intellisense/auto-complete recognizes the available namespaces within the solution I add it to?

I did a couple of tests and I figure that (by default) the linked file only uses the namespaces found inside a locally available solution (the first solution file found up it's path hierarchy).
e.g: If the .cs file is contained within an empty folder, is searches up looking for a .sln file, if none are found at the end of the search then no outside namespaces will be available when I edit the file.

Disclaimer: I don't know much about how Visual Studio works and I couldn't find any resources online to verify that, or much information about "linked files" in general actually.

I intend to copy the file to the build:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="C:\Users\User\QuantConnect\User\**\*.cs*">
  <Link>SkyLightProjects\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Compile>
```

**Is it possible to add a external .cs file (as a link) to a solution and edit it using intellisense with namespaces from the solution it was added to?**

I'm using the latest at the time of writing (16.7.3) Visual Studio Community 2019 IDE.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Available namespaces and types come from the current Solution and its references. A .cs file in a Solution's project is treated the same, whether it resides in the project subdirectory itself, or is linked from another location. Do note that for a .cs file to gain Intellisense support, it has to be part of a _project_. It is possible to add any file as a Solution item, but such files are not part of any compiled project and so don't have any project references to support Intellisense with.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips. I'm still a bit confused. If I add the .cs file as a link to a project within the solution, does it become "part of the project"? I ask because doing this alone does not seem to gain Intellisense support; it seems I have to create a separate project where the .cs file resides and seperately add all references for the desired Intellisense support, which in that case I may as well just use this second project (but unfortunately I can't due to issues with the way a third party app operates). Does all of that make sense, or is there something missing / going wrong?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Maybe to make things clearer, if I were to use the code shown above in my question within my .csproj to add .cs files as links, would the included .cs files have Intellisense support for namespaces available in that .csproj? (while editing the file in the solution containing the project) Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: _"If I add the .cs file as a link to a project within the solution, does it become "part of the project"?"_ -- yes. As long as it's in the project, it will (should be) compiled with the project, just like any other .cs file. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a very good place to try to diagnose these kinds of issues. It's impractical to try to replicate the scenario in this format, and without replication, it's impossible to know for certain what the issue is.

Comment: Your best bet would be to just learn more about how .csproj files work. As a start, create a couple of test projects, in separate Solutions. Make the projects identical, except for a single .cs file which is directly part of one project, and added as a linked file in the other. Then compare the .csproj files so that you understand the difference in that configuration. Then you can verify that your real-world scenario is working similarly.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the clarification from Peter, I found that it is possible and should have worked by default.

There was probably a bug somewhere in my project files, as I ended up resolving this issue by simply adding (one of) the .cs file not as a link, and then removing it. Somehow that resolved the issue and I now have Intellisense support with my linked .cs files.

I couldn't find and changes in my .csproj file so I really don't know what fixed it.